# how to make htop to display network info and IO info like this?

Tags: linux, htop

recently I see this htop screenshot with network info displayed also the IO tab and main tab

[htop with I/O tab and network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvBgX.png)

> below the SWAP area, there is a disk IO summary , and then an
> individual IO tab , in right-side below load average , the network
> speed info.

I have been googling around a bit , but didn't find anything useful

How can I get a `htop` like this ?

I assume it's like custom compiled one ?

I have checked through F2 setup option , but didn't see any network ...

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/25034

Comment: no , did you see my screenshot ?   it's not the IO column , but an individual IO tab

Comment: It's not the same, but look at Glances https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Tabs in *htop*](https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/pull/780) are a new feature. It is not yet part of an officially released *htop* version. If you want them, you need to build *htop* yourself.

Keep in mind that, after a long period of little activity, *htop* is now under *very* active development.

Answer (score 15):

Since **version 3.2.0** you can activate the tab view by setting the checkmark 'Show tabs for screens' in the 'Setup' page (shortcut <kbd>F2</kbd>).

Activation of tabs in Setup page:

[image: Activation of tabs in Setup page]

Answer (score 3):

For those who have older versions of htop, you can actually add the IO rate columns to the existing view even though there is no I/O tab.

- Go to setup (shortcut `F2`)
- In "Setup" go to "Columns"
- In "Available Columns" go to the columns you want (eg. IO_RATE)
- Press `F5` to add the column to "Active Columns"
  In the "Active Columns" you can order the columns using `F7` and `F8` if you want the new column in another position.